# internal error when searching nearGeoPoint

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm using parse sdk and when i try to search nearGeoPoint I get

```
2016-05-01 18:33:17.275 Partee[2557:1416403] [Error]: internal error (Code: 1, Version: 1.13.0)
2016-05-01 18:33:17.275 Partee[2557:1416403] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 1 after sleeping for 1.965591 seconds.
```

the code I'm using is

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Parties")
let myLocation = currentuser?.objectForKey("location") as! PFGeoPoint
query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: myLocation, withinKilometers: 100)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) in
      if error == nil {
           print("\(objects?.count) searches found")
      }
    }
})
```

where currentuser has "location" as his current location already saved, so I'm trying to search parties near 100 kilometer of that user but I keep getting that error, if i comment **nearGeoPoint** line then it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on migrating from Parse to MongoDB on mLab.

You need to add a 2d index to your GeoPoint field. If you are using MongoDB, do either of the following.

**Mongo Shell:**

```
db.test.createIndex({ "userLocation": "2d" })
```

Eg. Where 'test' is your collection name and 'userLocation' is the name of your GeoPoint field inside this collection.

**mLab UI Dashboard:**

Go to your database.
Go to the Collection that has the GeoPoint field causing the problem. Go to 'Indexes' on the top bar. Select 'Add Index' Input for example:

```
{ "userLocation" : "2d" }
```

Eg. Where 'userLocation' is the name of your GeoPoint field inside this collection.

That should fix it.

Comment: actually  I haven't migrated yet, using parse.com