# MongoDB & Parse Server - Can not query based on geoPoint

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, pfquery, mongodb-geospatial

Simple Query:

```
PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Adventures"];
[query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:self.userLocation withinMiles:100];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {}];
```

The `self.userLocation` is a PFGeoPoint.

I added an index on mongo thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967044/internal-error-when-searching-neargeopoint):

```
{ "userLocation" : "2d" }
```

I am pretty sure the error comes from how I am creating the `location` field in my `Adventure` class. I am using pymongo to access my MongoDB and using this code to create the `location` objects:

```
def createPFGeoPoint():
    for x in Adventures.find():
        if "longitude" in x and "latitude" in x:
            ##x['location']=json.dumps({"__type": "GeoPoint", "coordinates": [x['longitude'], x['latitude']]});
            x['location']=[x['longitude'], x['latitude']];
            ## save is deprecated but insert_one throws an error: duplicate key error collection: database.Adventures 
            Adventures.save(x)
```

[Parse](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#geopoint) says to create a JSON object like `{"__type": "GeoPoint","latitude": 40.0,"longitude": -30.0}`.
[Mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/) says to create a JSON object like `{ type: "Point", coordinates: [ 40, 5 ] }`. When trying the above, it comes out as a string type and I'm pretty sure it needs to be an array of the coordinates because:

When I upload a PFGeoPoint using the IOS Parse framework it comes out as an array [image]

When saving the `location` as an array like this `[-71.12345, 50.12345]` I print it out on the client side and the location object IS recognized as a PFGeoPoint. So I assumed I was creating them correctly.

Finally on the server side I am getting this error:

> error: Parse error: MongoError: unknown operator: $maxDistance

Querying just the `Adventure` class returns results. Querying with just `nearGeoPoint:` returns nothing but no error. Querying `nearGeoPoint: withinMiles:` returns an error.

Comment: Could you share how is the schema for Adventures class after these operations? Why are you saving the data directly in Mongo and not using Parse API for that?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo This is data from an excel sheet so it was easier using Mongo to upload the entire sheet rather than looping through and using Parse API to create an object for each row. The schema when I upload a geopoint with Parse API is....location : "geopoint"  and its type is a string. But it is shown as an array in the collection

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. I'd try to first delete the column, then create the column using the dashboard making sure its type is set to GeoPoint. Then try to upload the data directly in MongoDB. The format when uploading must be `{__type:'GeoPoint',latitude:XXX,longitude:YYY}`. Give it a try and let me know.